# Launch screen integration using info.plist in XCode 12

Tags: swift, launch-screen, xcode12.3

I am trying Configuring launch screens per URL scheme
Here is the screenshot of my info.plist.[image]

But only default launch screen is working and I am unable to load alternative launch screen.
Please highlight what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `User-Defined` build settings, so you can define a string containing the proper Launch Screen name for each scheme.

App target > Build Settings > + > Add User-Defined Settings
[image: step one]

Create your own key, in this example I'll be using `LAUNCH_SCREEN`

[image: step two]

Add values for each scheme

[image: step three]

Implementation on .plist
[image: implementation]

I Hope I Helped!